# SwiftMailer returns empty array

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I am teaching myself php and how to use Swiftmailer. I have followed the doc and added the code below to my php file, but it returns array( ). I can't figure out what could be wrong and how to check. I don't seem to have access to the remote server's ini file from the hosting provider. Would appreciate any help in determining what may be wrong and how to correct. thanks!

```
require_once 'Swift/lib/swift_required.php';    
//Use simple mail transport
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();

// Create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$message->setTo("xxx@yyy.com");

$message->setSubject("This email is sent using Swift Mailer");
$message->setBody("You're our best client ever.");
//$message->setFrom($email);
$message->setFrom("xxx@zzz.net");
$message->setReturnPath('xxx@zzz.net');


// Send the email
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$mailer->send($message, $failedRecipients);

// Show failed recipients
print_r($failedRecipients);
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what goes wrong? Do you get an error?

Comment: Maybe there are simply no failed recipients?